# Flashing/blinking TextView after CountDownTimer ends

Tags: java, android

I have an app that creates questions (sums) for the user that includes a timer. Once the timer reaches zero, the score is displayed to the user as well as a `TextView` that says ***Play Again?***

The code runs fine until I implement the flashing/blinking (animation sets TextView color and then transparent). Once the `Play Again?` is clicked, the app stops but doesn't crash. I think it is because the `playAgain()` method isn't called?

I want to keep the object oriented approach which is why I created a separate method for the animation called `flashPlay()`.

Here is the `playAgain()` code:

```
 public void playAgain (View v) {
        score = 0;
        numOfSums = 0;
        timeTextView.setText("30");
        scoreTextView.setText("0 : 0");
        resultTextView.setText("");
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button0.setEnabled(true);
        button1.setEnabled(true);
        button2.setEnabled(true);
        button3.setEnabled(true);
        playAgainButton.setEnabled(true);
        createQuestion();
        textViewTimesUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new CountDownTimer(3100, 1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                button0.setEnabled(false);
                button1.setEnabled(false);
                button2.setEnabled(false);
                button3.setEnabled(false);
                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                timeTextView.setText("0");
                textViewTimesUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flashPlay(); //calling the flashPlay() method. 

                if (score >= 1 && numOfSums >= 1) {
                    int percent =((score * 100) / numOfSums);
                    resultTextView.setText("Score: " + percent + "%");
                    textViewTimesUp.setText("Time's Up!");
                    questionTextView.setText("");

                } else {
                    textViewTimesUp.setText("Time's Up!");
                    questionTextView.setText("");
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

And here is the flashPlay() code:

```
 public void flashPlay () {
        final ObjectAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(playAgainButton, "textColor", Color.CYAN, Color.TRANSPARENT);

        colorAnim.setDuration(600); //duration of flash
        colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        colorAnim.start();

        playAgainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                colorAnim.end();
            }
        });
    }
```

Can someone show me whats wrong with the code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my app, i just blink my textView with this animation:

```
public static Animation blinkAnim() {

       // Configure your animation properties here

        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        animation.setDuration(550);
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(10);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        return animation;
    }
```

You can anim it by doing:

```
// get the animation
Animation anim = blinkAnim();
// start the animation
myTextView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I just used `clearAnimation()` and `setEnabled()` to finish it up.

Answer (score 1):

Sth like this? You should set the OnClickListener once in onCreate(). In flashPlay() it would have been set again every time the method gets called.

```
ObjectAnimator colorAnim = null;

onCreate(){
    ...
    playAgainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                if(colorAnim != null && colorAnim.isStarted()){
                    colorAnim.end();
                    //playAgain(v); ?
                }
            }
        });
    ...
}
...

public void flashPlay () {
        colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(playAgainButton, "textColor", Color.CYAN, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        colorAnim.setDuration(600); //duration of flash
        colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        colorAnim.start();
    }
```